# Error on apache2 restart using mod_python: "undefined symbol: sincos"

Tags: python, apache

I've tried installing mod_pyton 3.5.0 on my server, running apace2 and get the following error message when trying to restart apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restartapache2: Syntax error on line 244 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/python.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_python.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_python.so: undefined symbol: sincos
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

If it helps:
mod_python version 3.5.0
apache version 2.2.22 (Debian)
python version 3.4

Thanks for all help.

*update*

error log:

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Sun May 18 07:17:19 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 18 07:22:36 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun May 18 07:22:37 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 18 07:25:00 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun May 18 07:25:01 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 18 07:25:08 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun May 18 07:25:09 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 18 07:25:16 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun May 18 07:25:17 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 18 07:50:45 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun May 18 07:50:46 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 18 08:45:00 2014] [error] [client 157.56.93.103] File does not exist: /var/www/robots.txt
[Sun May 18 09:34:29 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/muieblackcat
[Sun May 18 09:34:33 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/phpMyAdmin
[Sun May 18 09:34:33 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/muieblackcat
[Sun May 18 09:34:34 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/phpmyadmin
[Sun May 18 09:34:34 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/phpAdmin
[Sun May 18 09:34:34 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/myadmin
[Sun May 18 09:34:35 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/phpMyAdmin
[Sun May 18 09:34:35 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/mysql
[Sun May 18 09:34:36 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/phpmyadmin
[Sun May 18 09:34:38 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/mysqladmin
[Sun May 18 09:34:40 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/myadmin
[Sun May 18 09:34:40 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/mysql
[Sun May 18 09:34:41 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/mysqladmin
[Sun May 18 09:34:41 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/websql
[Sun May 18 09:34:43 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/web
[Sun May 18 09:34:44 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/websql
[Sun May 18 09:34:45 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/pMA
[Sun May 18 09:34:45 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/pMA
[Sun May 18 09:34:48 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/MyAdmin
[Sun May 18 09:34:48 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/PHPMYADMIN
[Sun May 18 09:34:49 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/MyAdmin
[Sun May 18 09:34:49 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/PMA
[Sun May 18 09:34:49 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/PHPMYADMIN
[Sun May 18 09:34:49 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/SQL
[Sun May 18 09:34:50 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/db
[Sun May 18 09:34:50 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/PMA
[Sun May 18 09:34:51 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/dbadmin
[Sun May 18 09:34:51 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/SQL
[Sun May 18 09:34:51 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/pHpMyAdMiN
[Sun May 18 09:34:52 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/db
[Sun May 18 09:34:52 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/pma
[Sun May 18 09:34:54 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/dbadmin
[Sun May 18 09:34:54 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/sql
[Sun May 18 09:34:54 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/pHpMyAdMiN
[Sun May 18 09:34:55 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/pma
[Sun May 18 09:34:56 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/sql
[Sun May 18 09:34:57 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/MySQLAdmin
[Sun May 18 09:35:01 2014] [error] [client 61.191.62.7] File does not exist: /var/www/MySQLAdmin
[Sun May 18 13:43:17 2014] [error] [client 66.249.70.135] File does not exist: /var/www/robots.txt
[Sun May 18 13:57:33 2014] [error] [client 61.147.67.88] File does not exist: /var/www/w00tw00t.at.blackhats.romanian.anti-sec:)
[Sun May 18 13:57:33 2014] [error] [client 61.147.67.88] File does not exist: /var/www/phpMyAdmin
[Sun May 18 13:57:34 2014] [error] [client 61.147.67.88] File does not exist: /var/www/phpmyadmin
[Sun May 18 13:57:35 2014] [error] [client 61.147.67.88] File does not exist: /var/www/pma
[Sun May 18 13:57:35 2014] [error] [client 61.147.67.88] File does not exist: /var/www/myadmin
[Sun May 18 13:57:36 2014] [error] [client 61.147.67.88] File does not exist: /var/www/MyAdmin
[Sun May 18 19:12:09 2014] [error] [client 157.55.32.147] File does not exist: /var/www/robots.txt
```

apache conf file:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2-common/README.Debian.gz about
# Debian specific hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf.d
#   |   `-- *
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
#   In order to avoid conflicts with backup files, the Include directive is
#   adapted to ignore files that:
#   - do not begin with a letter or number
#   - contain a character that is neither letter nor number nor _-:.
#   - contain .dpkg
#
#   Yet we strongly suggest that all configuration files either end with a
#   .conf or .load suffix in the file name. The next Debian release will
#   ignore files not ending with .conf (or .load for mods-enabled).
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections, and which
#   of these ports are used for name based virtual hosts.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/ and sites-enabled/ directories
#   contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules or virtual
#   host configurations, respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * Configuration files in the conf.d directory are either provided by other
#   packages or may be added by the local administrator. Local additions
#   should start with local- or end with .local.conf to avoid name clashes. All
#   files in conf.d are considered (excluding the exceptions noted above) by
#   the Apache 2 web server.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the LockFile documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#lockfile>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5

##
## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
## 

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadLimit: ThreadsPerChild can be changed to this maximum value during a
#              graceful restart. ThreadLimit can only be changed by stopping
#              and starting Apache.
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# event MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#

AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

#
# DefaultType is the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
# It is also possible to omit any default MIME type and let the
# client's browser guess an appropriate action instead. Typically the
# browser will decide based on the file's extension then. In cases
# where no good assumption can be made, letting the default MIME type
# unset is suggested  instead of forcing the browser to accept
# incorrect  metadata.
#
DefaultType None


#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on and which to use for name based vhosts
Include ports.conf

#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
# If you are behind a reverse proxy, you might want to change %h into %{X-Forwarded-For}i
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see the comments above for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
Include conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/

ServerName localhost

# mod_python
LoadModule python_module modules/mod_python.so
```

Comment: what about showing your config file and "The Apache error log"?

Comment: sorry; added these
didn't add the error log as it did not appear to have anything related to the mod_python problem...
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

1. Before compiling mod_python 3.5.0 - need patch the configure.in for enable LDLIBS environment using with command: `sed -e 's/^\([ \t]*LDLIBS=\)/\1"\${LDLIBS} "/' -i configure.in`
2. Require again run: `autoconf`
3. Require run *configure* with *LDLIBS="-lm"*: `LDLIBS="-lm" ./configure`
4. Continue to build mod_python as usual: `make && make install`

Explanation:

The "***sincos***" function used in glibc in the library "libm.so". The above proposed solution makes the module to link with this library:

> $ ldd mod_python.so
>
> ...
>
> libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2b544ad000)

The old version of httpd server was linked with "m" library, but the new - not. So previously mod_python was not required to link with "m" individually.

The old httpd:

> $ /usr/sbin/httpd2 -V
>
> Server version: Apache/2.2.12
>
> $ ldd /usr/sbin/httpd2
>
> ...
>
> libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff010974000)

The new httpd:

> $ /usr/sbin/httpd -V
>
> Server version: Apache/2.4.6
>
> $ ldd /usr/sbin/httpd  | grep libm
>
> [empty]